# how can i convert this output to binary

Tags: python

I want to convert this result to binary and save it as a txt file. 
I currently knew how to save it as a txt file,
 but I haven't been able to find a way to convert the result to binary. 
Help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUH4A.png)

and this is part of the code

---

```
layer1lw = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0][:,:,0,:]
blayer=layer1lw*512
for i in range(0,3):
    for j in range(0,3):
        for k in range(0,32):
            blayer[i,j,k]=int(blayer[i,j,k])
print(blayer)
print(blayer[1,1,:])
for i in range(1,26):
    plt.subplot(5,5,i)
    plt.imshow(layer1lw[:,:,i],interpolation="nearest",cmap="gray")
plt.show()

model1.summary()
import sys
sys.stdout = open('output1.txt','w')



print(int_array)
```

---

thank you.

Comment: Do you want the graph as binary or the numbers as a binary file type?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
with open('output1.txt', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(bytes(int_array))
```

Assuming all bytes in the array are less than 256, this will write them all in raw binary to your file (which won't be a `.txt` file openable in a text editor anymore)

Answer (score 0):

pathlib has a way that you can remember which format you are using.
and converting text to binary is encoding it using the format you think you are using on screen... like "ascii"

```
from pathlib import Path
data = mystringcontents.encode('ascii')
output = Path('output1.txt')
output.write_bytes(data)
```